# How to format the call to the "do" entry point on manager.tz contracts in order to transfer funds to account X"

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, contract, kt1

I accidentally set the account manager for a smart contract to a baker I was trying to delegate to.

https://better-call.dev/main/KT1VSiaepk9USGAHDjJQAm4aaYRC6J8dTBHG/operations

Now I need to figure out how they can send the coins to me since my ledger is the smart contract owner and their wallet is the manager...

the storage has the value tz1WpeqFaBG9Jm73Dmgqamy8eF8NWLz9JCoY as that is what I provided in the --init of the origination I submitted.

Is there anyway to do this besides flying to Germany with my ledger?

Comment: So I went ahead and tested this, once the manager is set the manager can import the KT1 address and then move the funds to wherever he/she wants to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to edit the "do" entry point since they are the manager.  All that is required is for them to import the KT1 address into their wallet and they can send the funds.